# When a function $f$ is strictly increasing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, monotone-functions

Say $f$ is a real valued function that is differentiable (and continuous) whose domain is $[a,b]$. If
\begin{equation}
 f'(x) > 0, \forall x\in(a,b] \text{ and } f'(a) = 0
\end{equation}
Can I say that $f$ is strictly increasing in $[a,b]$ or the only thing that I can derive from the above is that it's strictly increasing in $(a,b]$?

**Example**:
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \frac{2 + x^5}{8}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
g'(x) = \frac{5x^4}{8}
\end{equation}
now it's obvious that $ g'(x) >0, \forall x \in (0,1]$, therefore $g$ is strictly increasing in $(0,1]$. Is there anyway (if it's true) I can say that $g$ is strictly increasing in $[0,1]$?

**My effort:**
Let $x\in(a,b]$, then $f$ is:
\begin{equation}
\left.\begin{array}{c}
\text{continuous in $[a,x]$} \\
\text{differentiable in $(a,x)$}
\end{array}\right\} \overset{\text{M.V.T}}{\implies} \text{There exists a $\xi \in (a,x)$ such that}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
f'(\xi) = \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}
\end{equation}
But we know that $f'(y) > 0, \forall y\in(a,b] \supset (a,b)$ and $x-a > 0$ since $x\in (a,b]$. Therefore it must be that:
\begin{equation}
f(x) - f(a) >0, \text{ where $x\in(a,b]$}
\end{equation}
Thus, $f$ is strictly increasing in $[a,b]$.
Is my proof correct?

Comment: $f(x)-f(a)>0$ for $x >a$ by Mean Value Theorem and this makes $f$ strictly increasing in $[a,b]$.

Comment: g(x)>g(0) for all x>0 so g is strictly increasing

Comment: Yes, you can so so @Nyquist-er

Comment: It should be $g'(x) > 0$ for all $x\in (0,1]$, not $<0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, I edited my question providing an effort of a proof, is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you absolutely can, you just need to have $f \in C^0([a,b])$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ with $f'>0$. I'm writing an answer but I suggest you try on your own first

Obviously it is strictly increasing on $(a,b)$, so we just need to ensure that $a < x \implies f(a) < f(x)$. If you suppose that $f(a) \geqslant f(x)$, you'll necessarily have $\forall y \in (a,x), \, f(y) < f(a)$, and in particular
$$\forall z \in \left(a, a + \frac{x-a}{2}\right],\quad f(z) \leqslant f\left(a + \frac{x-a}{2}\right) < f(a) $$
Then you take the limit for $z \rightarrow a$, and you get $f(a) < f(a)$ which is absurd.

Note that with my proof, I don't even need $f$ to be differentiable, only strictly increasing on $(a,b)$.

Comment: The condition $f'>0$ can be relaxed. For example, if $f' \ge 0$ and $f'=0$  only at isolated points, the conclusion is the same.

Comment: Can still apply mean value theorem?

Comment: as @PierreCarre said there are multiple cases where it is still true and $f' =0$ on some points, but there is no necessary and sufficient condition of $f'$ for the strict increase of $f$.